# How can I detect interactions with UIPickerView, when I don't own the delegate

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

Background:
I'm developing a plugin for other app developers to use. If they have a UIPickerView, I want to be able to react when the user interacts with the PickerView.

This means I can't set the UIPickerViewDelegate. For UITextFields I can use addTarget since it extends from UIControl. So how would I go about listening to changes in the UIPickerView when I do not know it's context? I'd prefer to do it in Swift.

Comment: You can use categories and make the onValueChanged send a notification.
Whoever wants to comply to that UIPickerView needs to just observe that notification.

Comment: Could you elaborate? I can't find a onValueChanged within the UIPickerView. Given that it exists, how do I detect changes on it? And I can't override the didSelectItem method since that would mess with it's implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can set the `UIPickerViewDelegate` to be your plugin, and delegate (some of) the functions out via a custom `YourPluginDelegate`. In this way both you and the your user will be able to detect the events. And it's one more layer of abstraction away from you implementation.

Code Example:

Your plugin:

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView,
        titleForRow row: Int,
        forComponent component: Int) -> String!{

        //do your things here

        let response = self.pluginDelegate.plugin(self, titleForRow: row, forComponent: component)
        return response
}
```

YourPluginDelegate:

```
protocol YourPlugInDelegate{
    func plugin(plugin:PlugIn, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component:Int)->String!
}
```